# How can I disable parent menu item links?

Tags: menus, customization

I don't want to have the parent menu items of my site's nav menus linking to a separate page. For one thing I don't want to have a superfluous page. For another these links hobble site navigation for mobile users who can't "hover" over a link (to bring up the child items).

The best solution would be to disable the parent menu item links. But how do I do that, especially now that with WordPress 3.5 the Disable Parent Menu Item plugin has stopped working?

One possible solution is [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/used-to-work?replies=9#post-3742289).

Answer (score 1):

Do not create fake URLs (`#`). This would be very bad for users with a screen reader: the are using a list of available links to browse your site. The same is true for `javascript:` links, they are not exactly elegant markup anyway.

You need two steps:

1. Mark the items with children before the walker starts.
2. Replace the markup for the top parents.

I will use an empty `<a>` element here to make it easy to get the cursor. You will probably need something like this in your stylesheet:

```
.menu > .has-children {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The filter to mark parent items is taken from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/78672/73). The second function just checks for that property and it tests if the item is itself not a child item.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects',      't5_add_has_children_to_nav_items' );
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 't5_unlink_parent_item', 10, 4 );

/**
 * Add aproperty 'has_children' to menu items
 *
 * @wp-hook wp_nav_menu_objects
 * @param   array $items
 * @return  array
 */
function t5_add_has_children_to_nav_items( $items )
{
    $parents = wp_list_pluck( $items, 'menu_item_parent' );
    $out     = array ();

    foreach ( $items as $item )
    {
        in_array( $item->ID, $parents ) && $item->has_children = TRUE;
        $out[] = $item;
    }
    return $items;
}
/**
 * Replace top parent element markup.
 *
 * @wp-hook walker_nav_menu_start_el
 * @param   string $item_output
 * @param   object $item
 * @param   int    $depth
 * @param   object $args
 * @return  string
 */
function t5_unlink_parent_item( $item_output, $item, $depth, $args )
{
    // not first level parent item
    if ( empty ( $item->has_children ) or 0 != $item->menu_item_parent )
        return $item_output;

    $title = apply_filters(
        'the_title',
        $item->title,
        $item->ID
    );
    $id = apply_filters(
        'nav_menu_item_id',
        'menu-item-'. $item->ID,
        $item, $args
    );
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
    $classes[] = 'has-children';
    $class_names = join(
        ' ',
        apply_filters(
            'nav_menu_css_class',
            array_filter( $classes ),
            $item,
            $args
        )
    );
    $class_names = $class_names
        ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"'
        : '';

    return "<li$id>$args->before<a class='menu-item has-children'>$title</a>$args->after";
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine but it indicates a fundamental flaw in WordPress menus that this much code is needed to achieve what should be a simple thing :)

Comment: @JCL1178 I guess not many authors use a `href`-less top level. And most custom themes use a custom walker anyway. I see the native implementation as a starting guide that works in most cases but isn’t forced onto the developer.

Comment: Thanks for your lengthy reply, toscho. You put a lot of work into it I can see. Actually, the answer in the link I posted says to _remove_ the hash symbol, so there's no hash symbol in the link that appears in the menu: it becomes a link without an `href`, i.e., no URL, fake or otherwise. Since your solution seems to depend on evacuating the `href` as well, I wonder how it is better for screen-readers. Is your walker worthwhile?

Comment: @JohnK The plugin from that thread is probably the worst possible attempt to solve that issue. You _will_ get conflicts with other plugins with that, because it calls `wp_print_scripts` a second time. This should never have passed the plugin review … Anyway, use the PHP solution here; it is free of side effects, except when you use a plugin that comes with its own custom walker.

Comment: The link wasn't to the plug-in, toscho, but to a simple, 'by-hand' way to replace it in making a non-clickable menu item. Seems to produce the same effect as your code. I'd like to give you credit for your work, but I can only choose yours as the correct answer if you somehow justify its superiority over the simple way.

Comment: Oh, I see. What ever fits best for your case is fine. My solution works automatically, the other one needs manual tweaking. I prefer solutions that just work. But if you are fine with some extra steps, do it so.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply create custom menu items with a javascript:void(0) as the href whenever a parent item is needed.

Comment: Good answer, and a much better solution than using hash symbol as the link as indicated in the posters link.

Comment: Actually if you read carefully, that solution says to remove the hash symbol, so there's no hash symbol in the link.

Comment: But how? can you give a example?

Answer (score 0):

Works with WordPress 3.5:

1. Add a *Link* entry with the name you want and a # URL
2. Edit the menu entry you just created and remove the #

You have to do both steps, as you can't add a menu entry with an empty URL.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

A little late but for future use.  You can create a custom link for the parent.  When you add it you have to add a #, but once it's added you can remove it which disables the link.

Answer (score -1):

To eliminate the active "hover" cursor:

Theme Options > Drop down menu > Make parent menu items clickable : disable