# If child is active add class to parent in customWalker

Tags: menus

Im writing a customWalker for the wordpress main navigation area.

But i am a little stuck on how to find and add a class to the parent of the child which is active.

For instance

I have the whole customwalker working perfect, all parents have a active class assigned when they are active, but how to I assign an active class to the parent when a sub class is active?

I managed to assign a active class to the top depth when current_page_item was given like this:

```
if($depth === 0){
            $class_names = str_replace('current_page_item', 'active', $class_names);
        }
```

But how would I write it for a child class to show the parent an active when the child is active?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82107/73)? The first part of the code solves your problem.

Comment: @toscho This just asks if has children, I have this already, I am wanting to know the logic to add a class to the parent when the child is active. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, WordPress applies ancestor classes to the parents of active items. All you have to do is target them via CSS:

```
.nav-menu li.current_page_ancestor > a,
.nav-menu li.current-menu-ancestor > a {}
```

This code sample implies that your menu has the `.nav-menu` class. This will work with a navigation menu and with the page menu fallback.